# Android-Cordova 10.0.1 Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

I have upgraded the cordova-android version from 9.0 to 10.0.1 and facing the below issues while building the Cordova app using - ionic cordova build android

Errors:

```
Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.    
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
```

**Info**:

Cordova CLI - 10.0.0

Cordova android: 10.0.1

Node: v12.18.2

npm: 6.14.13

**Project Installed Plugins**:

```
@havesource/cordova-plugin-push: 2.0.0
    cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release: 4.0.0
    cordova-background-geolocation-lt: 4.0.1
    cordova-plugin-advanced-http: 3.1.0
    cordova-plugin-android-permissions: 1.1.2
    cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: 1.1.3
    cordova-plugin-androidx: 3.0.0
    cordova-plugin-app-launcher: 0.4.0
    cordova-plugin-app-version: 0.1.12
    cordova-plugin-appminimize: 1.0.1
    cordova-plugin-background-fetch: 7.0.1
    cordova-plugin-badge: 0.8.8
    cordova-plugin-camera: 5.0.2
    cordova-plugin-device: 2.0.3
    cordova-plugin-file-opener2: 3.0.5
    cordova-plugin-file: 6.0.2
    cordova-plugin-filepath: 1.6.0
    cordova-plugin-googlemaps: 2.7.1
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser: 5.0.0
    cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard: 2.2.0
    cordova-plugin-ionic-webview: 4.2.1
    cordova-plugin-local-notification: 0.9.0-beta.2
    cordova-plugin-market: 1.2.0
    cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps: 2.0.2
    cordova-plugin-network-information: 2.0.2
    cordova-plugin-sim: 1.3.3
    cordova-plugin-sms-retriever-manager: 1.0.2
    cordova-plugin-splashscreen: 6.0.0
    cordova-plugin-statusbar: 2.4.3
    cordova-plugin-twilio-chat: 3.3.0
    cordova-plugin-whitelist: 1.3.4
    cordova-sqlite-storage: 6.0.0
    phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner: 8.1.0
    phonegap-plugin-multidex: 1.0.0
```

Can anyone have an idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved this by using adding the below preferences in config.xml file:

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" />
 
 <!-- Updated the version of com.google.gms.google-services -->
<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.8" /> ,
```

Package.json:

```
"cordova-android": "^10.1.0"
```

Gradle version: 7.1.1

- [https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip"](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip%22)

Answer (score 1):

It finally worked for me. I changed the gradle version used to 6.7.1 and reinstall some outdated cordova plugins.

plugins used:

```
@havesource/cordova-plugin-push 2.0.0 "Cordova Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.5.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-camera 5.0.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 6.4.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 8.5.0 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inject-cookie 1.0.2 "WKWebViewInjectCookie"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
```

Comment: Can you send me the plugin versions you are using? So, I can upgrade those and check it

Comment: Answers are updated with plugins currently used. Have you tried using gradle 6.7.1?

Comment: Whitelist plugin is deprecated for cordova android 10. and it is not supported. How were you able to build using version 10? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the provided answers were helpful.
Take a look here [fix-google-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69856650/build-failing-after-upgrade-cordova-android-10/70111440#70111440) for other solution in config, maybe for somebody it will help.

I have 9.1.0 version of 'cordova-android' which is not supporting Android API 30+ [Android API Levels and Android Versions](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/)

How I fixed the issue OR how I hack the solution:
Run:

1. cordova platform rm  android
2. cordova platform add android

This should generate a "build.gradle" file in platforms\android
Then, manually change "project.ext" part of code and specify version which you want, in my case I need to support 30 API version:

```
project.ext {
  defaultBuildToolsVersion="30.0.0" //String
  defaultMinSdkVersion=23 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
  defaultTargetSdkVersion=30 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
  defaultCompileSdkVersion=30 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}
```

You can modify sh script proposed by [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2942211/mike) (in 1 link) for this needs.

Btw, when i was trying to fix the issue on cordova-android version 10 - this block of code was even not presented in "build.gradle".

What protentionally could help too:

1. Remove cordova-plugin-whitelist - it is not supported from version 10.
2. In SDK Platforms manager - download needed API Level;
   [image]
3. In SDK Tools manager - download needed build tools version;
   [image]

Comment: We should not change the file manually in "platforms\android" which are auto generated.

Comment: @H_H yes, I agree also mentioned that it is a hack, because no other solutions didn`t work for me.