# Build failing after upgrade cordova-android 10

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-android

When I upgraded `cordova-android@9.0.0` to `cordova-android@10.1.1` I've got a build problem when I run `cordova build android --release --buildconfig=build.json`

Problems:

```
* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR1'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR1'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR2' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR2'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR2'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'searchedLocation' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.
    
    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add a getter for field 'searchedLocation'.
      2. Remove the annotations on 'searchedLocation'.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
```

I've already tried:

- Updated some dependencies outdated
- Remove `cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release` `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` `cordova-support-google-services`
- Add in `config.xml` 
   `<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled" value="true" />` and 
  `<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.8" />` 
   but when I did that, I've got another error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'.
   > Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

Ionic CLI: 5.4.16
Ionic Framework: ionic-angular 3.9.8
@ionic/app-scripts: 3.2.4

Cordova CLI: 10.0.0
Cordova Platorms: android 10.1.1

NodeJS: 12.19.0
Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really big thanks for your question & description of the problem, because it helped me to upgrade from cordova-android 9.1.0 to 10.1.1 :-).

And i think i can solve your problem. This error is thrown, because **google services plugin is registered twice** (apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') in gradle files, e.g.: platforms/android/app/build.gradle. You just have to comment/remove one of these imports.

Because cleaning files manually every time is very annoying, i created a bash script (= working on Mac OS), which comments the second import automatically: **fix_android.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Executing fix_android.sh"

## comment duplicate import of com.google.gms.google-services plugin
#file=$(pwd)"/platforms/android/app/build.gradle"
file="platforms/android/app/build.gradle"
#echo ${file}
from="apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"
to="\/\/apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
  if grep -lr "$to" "$file"; then
      echo "File already corrected!"
  else
      change=`sed "s/$from/$to/" < "$file"`
      echo "$change" > "$file"
      #echo "$change"
      echo "Commented duplicate import!"
  fi
else
  echo ${file}" not found!"
  ls -al platforms/android/app
fi
```

To start the script automatically before building, i use ionic building scripts/hooks in **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "ionic:build:before": "./scripts/fix_android.sh",
    "ionic:build:after": "",
    ...
```

This is my actual project & system configuration
[image]

Comment: Interesting... You know where/which plugin is causing this ? (registering multiple google services plugin)

Comment: I Added `<preference name="GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion" value="4.3.8" />` in `config.xml` and comment the duplicated line, the second erro was resolved but the first returned..

Comment: I had this problem about 2 month ago, while using cordova-support-google-services plugin. It seems that the plugin itself created 2 imports. 
After removing cordova-support-google-services plugin from package.json, i added the 2 new preference tags in config.xml and rei-installed all packages (without package-lock.json) to solve all errors. By the way, i use ionic cli 6.18.1 and upgraded to angular 12.2.13 and node.js 14.18.1 this week.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If it would help you, I can send you my config.xml & package.json.
You also have to set android-targetSdkVersion to 30 and android-minSdkVersion to 23 in config.xml. In my preparations i installed sdk build tools 30.0.3 (, because 31.0.0 are corrupted) and upgraded to gradle 7.2 too.

Comment: Yeah, solve our problem, apologies for the delay. But we were implementing and testing your solution in our CI, and seems it works great!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to hear you solved your problem, after you solved mine ;-).

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the provided answers were helpful.
Take a look here [config.xml-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756801/android-cordova-10-0-1-task-appprocessdebuggoogleservices-failed) for the solution in config, maybe for somebody it will help.

I have 9.1.0 version of 'cordova-android' which is not supporting Android API 30+ [Android API Levels and Android Versions](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/)

How I fixed the issue OR how I hack the solution:
Run:

1. cordova platform rm  android
2. cordova platform add android

This should generate a "build.gradle" file in platforms\android
Then, manually change "project.ext" part of code and specify version which you want, in my case I need to support 30 API version:

```
project.ext {
  defaultBuildToolsVersion="30.0.0" //String
  defaultMinSdkVersion=23 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.1
  defaultTargetSdkVersion=30 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
  defaultCompileSdkVersion=30 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}
```

You can modify sh script proposed by [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2942211/mike) for this needs.

Btw, when i was trying to fix the issue on cordova-android version 10 - this block of code was even not presented in "build.gradle".

What protentionally could help too:

1. Remove cordova-plugin-whitelist - it is not supported from version 10.
2. In SDK Platforms manager - download needed API Level;
   [image]
3. In SDK Tools manager - download needed build tools version;
   [image]